# google map not showing in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, iframe

i am loading a google map in to a iframe

```
    <iframe width="96%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=+&amp;q=55.95143146710088,-3.1784801483154&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.961432,-3.19848&amp;spn=0.001811,0.004823&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

This worked well on all browser except ie. In ie i got error in console that

```
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/myplaces/mp4.png
```

Using this error i made some investigation also some changes.  changed https to http in iframe src.But this won't help me. I copy this code snippet and create a basic html page Then this worked in all browsers . But when i integrate in to my portal then there will show that error. i can't figure the issue

Please help me.

Comment: Are you mixing http and https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mixing http and https?

If that is the case. take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx?PageIndex=7